# How to Update two text fields onchange of a dropdown list

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Im building a web app using the yii framework. I have a dropdownlist and im calling an action and updating a div tag using ajax array `'update'=>'#price'` field. the code works fine and it updates the price div.

But i want to update two fields like that, i tried passing an array to the update field. but it didnt work.

Any Idea how I can update two div tags and show two values using one action call?

Heres My Code..

```
 echo CHtml::beginForm();
 echo CHtml::dropDownList('amount_'.$position,'', array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3),
 array(
 'ajax' => array(
     'type'=>'POST', 
 'url'=>CController::createUrl('shoppingCart/updateAmount'), 
     'update'=>'#price_'.$position, //selector to update
  ))); 
  echo CHtml::endForm();
```

and in my action im just echoing

```
echo 'LKR '.Shop::priceFormat(@$product->getPrice($cart[$position]['Variations'], $value));
```

It'll be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply jQuery selector. I believe you can use comma for few ids. Or you can use class selector. (I think class selector would be better here)

```
'ajax' => array(
    /* ... */
    'update' => '#price_1, #price_2, #price_3',
    /* or */
    'update' => '.price'
)
```

Comment: im a bit new to JQuery...in this case in my action, how can u give two values? coz im echoing only one....

Comment: for example...if i wanna give price one value and total price another... how do i handle it in my action?

Comment: If you need to update different divs with different values, then you need success callback for your ajax call and return json from your Yii action. `Update` won't work in this case. Check [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).